# Tensorflow(Regression): How to implement a function in loss function

Tags: tensorflow

I want to design a NN in which the outputs of the NN plug in to my customized function (e.g. calculating something based on the outputs from the NN) and in the loss function, the error between the measurement and output of the function are minimized.

In my script,

```
y_pred = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(h4, 4, tf.nn.relu) 
#y_pred should be four numbers

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y,myfunction(y_pred[:,0],y_pred[:,1],y_pred[:,2],y_pred[:,3])))
```

then I have

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Would you recommend any solutions for my problem?

Comment: Could you please share the definition of `myfunction`?

Comment: eg) function f = -(one value from the output layer)*((second value from the output layer-third value from the output layer)/(fourth value from the output layer -3))

Comment: then I have measurements which are the function values. So I want to minimize the measurements - function.

Comment: I want to learn how to incorporate the science models such as diffusion equation with NN.

Comment: can you also share the traceback?